# Заливка файла по FTP

Tags: ftp, delphi

пытаюсь отправить по FTP на сервер использую такой код:

```
ftp := TIdFTP.Create(Application); //отправляем файл по FTP
ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
try
  try
    ftp.Host := HOST; // ftp адрес сервера
    ftp.Port := 21;
    ftp.Username := LOgin; // логин
    ftp.Password := Pass; // Пароль
    ftp.Connect;
    AssErt(ftp.Connected);
    ftp.ChangeDir('/'); // мне нужно залить в корень сайта тут всё ок
    ftp.Put('fresh-proxy.html', 'fresh-proxy.html', false); //Файл Откуда-Куда
    ShowMessage('Send HTML file');
  finally
    ms.Free;
    ftp.Free;
  end;
except
  ShowMessage('Error');
end;
```

Вылетает error но что самое странное на сервере всё-таки создаётся файл fresh-proxy.html но его вес равен 0.

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

Добавь перед коннектом

```
ftp.Passive:=true;
```